# How to turn number strings into integers?

Tags: python, string, integer

How do I turn the number strings into integers? I need the numbers made by this code to be integers, not strings.

```
def capital_indexes(big):
bog = "["
bug = 0
for letter in big:
    if letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
        bog = bog + str(bug) + ", "
        bug = bug + 1
    else:
        bug = bug + 1
bog = bog[:-2]
bog = bog + "]"

return bog
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This language is Python.

Comment: I googled and found https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-string-to-int/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Comment: Yes, but if you input a word to capital_indexes, say, "HeLlO", it would return [0, 2, 4], with 0, 2, 4 being strings. If I use the int() method, it would say that I cant turn [ and , to an int. I want to turn only the numbers into integers.

Comment: Strings have an `.isdigit` method that you can use when iterating over the string character by character. Maybe you are looking for the 1-liner `sum(int(c) for c in big if c.isdigit())`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to mean your output should be in python list not in str.

Here is solution how to print list:

```py
def capital_indexes(big):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(big)):
        if big[i] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            output.append(i)
    return output
```

Output:

```
>>> capital_indexes("aBrLT")
>>> [1, 3, 4]
```